# python itertools: How to roll N dice?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I can iterate through all combinations of 1, 2, or 3 6-sided dice with loops like these:

```
for a in range(1, 7):  # one die
  sum = a
  dosomething(sum)

for a in range(1, 7):  # two dice
  for b in range(1, 7):
    sum = a + b
    dosomething(sum)

for a in range(1, 7):    # three dice
  for b in range(1, 7):
    for c in range(1, 7):
      sum = a + b + c
      dosomething(sum)
```

How can I do this for N dice using itertools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what `itertools.product` is for.

```
for dice in itertools.product(range(1, 7), repeat=N):
    dosomething(sum(dice))
```